# NSMutableArray not in XML Format

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating an NSMutableArray using NSXMLParser, which then populates a UITableView, and it works fine. But I am unable to save the array to a text file, because it seems that my final array is not in the correct format.

I have setup the NSXMLParser like this:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
                                    namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
                                   qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
                                      attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:kEntryStr])
    {
        self.workingEntry = [[AppRecord alloc] init];
    }

    if (self.workingEntry)
        storingCharacterData = [elementsToParse containsObject:elementName];
    }
```

When I view the array using NSLog, instead of showing the array data, it shows something like this:

```
"<AppRecord: 0x1c00de840>",
"<AppRecord: 0x1c00de8b0>",
"<AppRecord: 0x1c00de920>",
"<AppRecord: 0x1c40ded10>",
"<AppRecord: 0x1c00de990>",
"<AppRecord: 0x1c40ded80>",
"<AppRecord: 0x1c00dea00>",
```

How can I properly convert this to normal strings that I can save to a text file?

Comment: You are asking how to persist an array of custom objects to a file. Does the file need to be text file or can it be in a binary format? If the latter, look into `NSCoding` and `NSKeyedArchiver`/`NSKeyedUnarchiver`.

Comment: Thanks. NSKeyedArchiver/NSKeyedUnarchiver looks like it may do the trick. It doesn't need to be a text file necessarily, but it just helps to be able to view the contents of the file if it is in text format.